# Glass Milk bottles?

Tags: bottling, fermenter, glass

Just about to start up my next batch and noticed I hac a couple glass milk bottles from Whole Foods lying around. In what ways could they be put to-use in homebrewing? Fermenting a test? Mead? Cider? Maybe just as an alternative when bottling?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can find stoppers at your local HBS that fit them, you can use them for yeast starters or small test batches. Since it's clear glass though, you might be better off getting your deposit back from whole foods.

Without a good cap and UV protection, they're not much use for bottling.

Comment: Those twist off caps are not very good for bottling because they don't hold as much pressure.  As Brandon mentioned, they might be useful for doing yeast starters.  The test batches would have to be super small though.

Answer (score 6):

Do not use milk bottles for bottling.  They can't withstand the pressure from carbonation and will be likely to explode.

Answer (score 0):

If you can find bungs that will fit them, they could be outfitted with an airlock and used for holding a little bit of extra wine/mead left when you rack from the primary, to be used for topping off the secondary further on down the line. You'd still need to make sure there was no extra airspace, though, so it would depend on the size of milk bottles you have, and how much extra you have left in your primary once you've racked to secondary.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a bad idea to run a "[wort stability test](http://www.wyeastlab.com/com-qc.cfm)" every now and then. A milk bottle would work for that. If you can find a bung with a hole in it (airlock setup), you could also use them for a "[Fast Fermentation Test](http://www.braukaiser.com/wiki/index.php?title=Fast_Ferment_Test)".